# Alexa rank issues problem

Tags: php, alexa-internet

One of my site have some administration files. This section can be access only whit user and password. All files have check login validation by php session.

If i access a specific file by broser whitout logging the browser redirect me to the login page. That's correct.

Anyway, i have some issues whit alexa rank that can access all files whitout login user & pass. How is that possible?

Comment: hi! when you perform your redirect, do you use the "header()" function ? If yes, do you kill php after sending this header (via exit() or die()) ? Seems that alexa does not follow your redirection header...

Comment: i have a "if..$_SESSION... { header('location:...'); }". Now i will put die(); and see if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Alexa toolbar will be sending the url of the page your looking at to their servers but I highly doubt it's getting past your security like you think it is. It's simply ranking the URL and not the content of the page.

Comment: Alexas toolbar may access the pages, when you or another user is logged in. This behaves completely different from other analytic-methods, like the ones from Google or Piwik. See: http://www.quantumseolabs.com/blog/marketing/accurate-alexa/